# not rendering metaball particle collisions

Tags: rendering, particles

I have a animated figure that has two particle systems,...one is a hair, the other is an emission,. Both use the same meatball instance object....the hair particles are used to define the figure shape. the emission particles emit from the figure and collides with a ground plane and accumulates. the total effect is a figure made of jelly is dancing and globs of jelly fall from the figure and collect on the ground around the figure. the issue I'm having is the collisions do not render in the animation, but render properly in the viewport render view. individual frames render correctly, but not in animation renders. included image single frame evee render. [image]

Comment: I know I've had problems in 2.79 when it came to metaball instances not being rendered, but 2.8 should have improved this? Are you able to bake the simulation? I know smoke comes and goes if it isn't baked.

Comment: I figured out the issue ….I needed to bake the emission particles in order to get the collisions to render properly in the animation.